Circuit breaker trips when ceiling fan wires are connected
House built 1964.
Ceiling fan has 4 black & 4 white wires. Runs my 2 bathrooms, garage, and bedroom. I know the 2 wires that control the fan but it trips when connected.

Do not believe white is always neutral.  64 they often used just a black/white cable to the switch, which means the white would be hot(not right but switched hot).  Most wires would be connected black to black/white to white, but one will be white to black.  Picture of the switch wires connected will help.

You took it all apart without noting how it was originally connected, and then put it all back together with black-to-black and white-to-white didn't you ... ?

Please post the picture you took of the wiring before you unwired everything. This may help us help you.

There are a number of possibilities. But a likely explanation of the 4 cables is:

A - Incoming power - either directly from the circuit breaker or from the previous room on this circuit
B - Switch loop - goes down to the wall switch for the fan
C - Ongoing power 1 - powers another room
D - Ongoing power 2 - powers another room

You need to identify the first two cables. Here is one way to do that. To do this right, I recommend getting both a non-contact voltage tester (NCVT) and a multimeter. One nice safe package is from Klein, available on Amazon and at Home Depot and other stores. There are other devices available and Klein is not the only reputable brand, but stay away from uncertified junk as you will be working with 120V here, not 5V.

To identify incoming power:

Turn off the breaker
Disconnect all the black and white wires and spread them apart
Turn on the breaker
Use the NCVT to determine which wire is hot - it should be just one black wire. If lots of wires show hot, use the multimeter to check voltage between each wire and ground. If you find more than one hot (120V) wire, STOP and ask for more help.
Turn off the breaker
Tag the black wire as incoming hot and the matching white wire as incoming neutral

To identify the switch loop:

Turn off the breaker
Turn on the fan wall switch (note: this test mode will not work if it is a smart switch - if so, ask for more help)
Use the multimeter to check for continuity between each black/white pair, except for the one already marked as incoming hot/neutral
For each pair that shows continuity, turn the switch off and confirm that the switch off breaks continuity
If you don't find any pairs that are continuous/not continuous with switch on/off, or if you find more than one, STOP and ask for more help.

Assuming the above worked (incoming hot/neutral identified, switch loop identified):

Mark the white wire of the switch loop with black tape (required)
Mark the black wire of the switch loop with red tape (not required, but recommended)
Mark the black wire of the fan with red tape (not required, but recommended)
Connect all of the white wires (except the white wire with the black tape) together and to the white wire of the fan
Connect all of the black wires (except the ones marked red) together
Connect all of the wires marked red together

With this scheme, wires marked with tape are treated as if they were those colors. And then:

White = Neutral
Black = Always Hot
Red = Switched Hot

